# Allowing some IPs in DOCKER-USER chain for inbound traffic, rejecting all the rest

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to allow only certain IP addresses to access ports exposed by docker containers on the host. All the rest external IPs should not be able to access them (even if I expose a port on `0.0.0.0`). There is a plenty of workarounds across the internet how to achieve that - starting with disabling iptables management for docker and manage all the iptables rules manually (which is not so cool, especially if you have to deal with docker swarm ingress routing etc.), till dirty solutions with resetting iptables rules with cronjobs and custom scripts. But hey, we have a `DOCKER-USER` chain, which seems to be suitable for such kind of stuff?

### The Docker-vs-Firewall Problem

As we know, upon startup docker adds some iptables chains and rules in order to do its networking magic. The thing is that it adds these chains at the very top of the `FORWARD` chain on every docker service restart, which means that all your predefined rules with rejects on that chain become completely useless. [Docker documentation suggests to use its `DOCKER-USER` chain for such kind of things](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#add-iptables-policies-before-dockers-rules) (rules in this chain stay persistent from docker's perspective and are executed before any other docker rules).

From the example in docker documentation we see that we can allow access for one IP (and deny for others) using

```
-I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

This command kind of works and only IP `1.2.3.4` can access docker's exposed ports. But **the problem is that in this case containers aren't able to connect to Internet**.

### So the situation is...

With

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination                  
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

everything works and all the external traffic is allowed, and with:

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  -- !1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

only IP `1.2.3.4` is allowed to access docker's exposed services (which is nice!), but there's no Internet connection from inside containers. That's a problem. No other iptables rules are added - only docker's default + this one custom DROP in `DOCKER-USER` chain. I was trying to `RETURN` internal IP ranges like `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16` in this chain (some of forum threads suggested to try that), so my chain had looked like:

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination       
RETURN     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     all  --  1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0             
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

but still no success - docker's exposed ports are accessible only from `1.2.3.4` (which is nice again), but still no Internet connection from the container.

Any ideas on why is this happening and how could I allow containers to communicate with outside world while restricting inbound traffic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you should restrict your rules to internet interface, seems like it applies to all interfaces

Answer (score 0):

```
*filter
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A DOCKER-USER -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -s A.B.C.D -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -i MY_WAN_INTERFACE_NAME -j DROP
```